# Why can't I change numbers as strings into integers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

I'm doing a kata that requires me to change two strings of numbers (given as "1 2 3 4 5 6" for example) to integers, adding those integers, and then determining which value is larger to print out a message.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def goodVsEvil(good, evil)
 goodarr = []
 evilarr = []

 goodarr.push(good.split(" "))
 evilarr.push(evil.split(" "))

 goodarr.each{|n| n.to_i}
 evilarr.each{|n| n.to_i}

 goodsum = goodarr.inject(:+)
 evilsum = evilarr.inject(:+)

 if goodsum > evilsum
   return "Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil"
 elsif goodsum < evilsum
   return "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good"
 elsif goodsum = evilsum
   return "Battle Result: No victor on this battle field"
 end
end
```

I'm splitting the string into individual numbers and pushing them into their respective arrays, but I need to convert them into integers and the interpreter won't recognize the `.to_i` method as a valid method.
How do I fix it or how am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least three mistakes here:

```
goodarr.push(good.split(" "))
```

this does not do what you think it does. Here you only add a single element to the array which is the result array from the call to `split`:

```
goodarr => [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
```

This means that each element in the array is an array, which have no `to_i` methods.

You should do this instead:

```
goodarr = good.split(" ")
```

or

```
goodarr = good.split # use spaces by default
```

A second mistake is this:

```
goodarr.each{|n| n.to_i}
```

This code has no side-effect at all. The values returned by the block are not stored anywhere. You need to use `map!` instead:

```
goodarr.map!{|n| n.to_i}
```

The last mistake is the use of the assignment operator `=` when you actually want to compare values equality using the equality operator `==`.

Comment: Final note the last conditional is using assignment `=` rather than equality `==`

Comment: May not be relevant to the question, but an alternative way to achieve the same would be using regular expression.
eg: good_sum = good.scan(/\d+/).collect(&:to_i).sum

Comment: @nkm My thought was to get the sum in a different way as well: `good_sum = eval(good.gsub(" ","+"))` also works.

Comment: @nkm `sum` is a `rails` method not implemented in ruby core. You would need to use `inject` or `reduce`. For Example I would change your method to `good.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)`

Comment: If you think there are only two mistakes you're not counting very well :)

Comment: @MichaelChaney I'm counting well enough,but I indeed didn't see the assignment issue ;)

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky for correcting me. @pjd generally it is a better practice to implement a method by expecting invalid parameters unless it is a private method, accordingly I would think twice before using eval.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down:

```
def goodVsEvil(good, evil)
 goodarr = []
 evilarr = []
```

There's really no need to "declare" your variables.

```
 goodarr.push(good.split(" "))
 evilarr.push(evil.split(" "))
```

You're pushing an array into an array here, so you end up with a one-element array, the single element being a multiple-element array.  It'll basically be this:

"1 2 3 4 5 6" turns into `[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`, which isn't what you want.  Direct assignment `evilarr=evil.split(" ")` is what you want.

```
 goodarr.each{|n| n.to_i}
 evilarr.each{|n| n.to_i}
```

These lines do nothing.  This doesn't affect each array.

```
 goodsum = goodarr.inject(:+)
 evilsum = evilarr.inject(:+)
```

And with all those issues these end up not working.

```
 if goodsum > evilsum
   return "Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil"
 elsif goodsum < evilsum
   return "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good"
 elsif goodsum = evilsum
   return "Battle Result: No victor on this battle field"
 end
end
```

And this code works except for `goodsum = evilsum`.  One "=" is assignment, "==" is comparison.

Here's what I would do:

```
def goodVsEvil(good,evil)
  goodsum = good.split(/\s+/).map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
  evilsum = evil.split(/\s+/).map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)

  if goodsum > evilsum
    return "Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil"
  elsif goodsum < evilsum
    return "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good"
  elsif goodsum == evilsum
    return "Battle Result: No victor on this battle field"
  end
end
```

Breaking it down:

1. `good.split(/\s+/)` - using a regular expression for splitting the string makes it accept dirtier input.
2. `.map(&:to_i)` - this will take the array of strings from last step, call the "to_i" method on each to create an integer, and then return the array of integers.
3. `.inject(0, :+)` - and this takes the array of integers, starts with 0 and adds each one, returning the sum.

Comment: Hooray for point out the assignment issue in the `if..elsif` conditionals.

Comment: If you're going to do a code review, might as well go all out.

Answer (score 1):

At first `split` returns an array. You don't need to create it at first. `each` iterates through an array only but it doesn't change its elements. Therefore you can use `map`.

```
def goodVsEvil(good, evil)
  goodarr = good.split(" ").map{|n| n.to_i}
  evilarr = evil.split(" ").map{|n| n.to_i}

  goodsum = goodarr.inject(:+)
  evilsum = evilarr.inject(:+)

  if goodsum > evilsum
    return "Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil"
  elsif goodsum < evilsum
    return "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good"
  elsif goodsum = evilsum
    return "Battle Result: No victor on this battle field"
  end
end

goodVsEvil("1 2 3 4 5 6", "1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
# => "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good"
```

You tried:

```
goodarr = []
goodarr.push(good.split(" "))
# => [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
```

This results in a nested array as you can see.